# Edit review: are extensive edits of accepted answer ok?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I was asked to review a proposed edit to an answer, and found it difficult to decide whether to accept or reject, because:

- The answer was an accepted answer with a dozen upvotes.
- The edit was extensive: it turned a short code example into several paragraphs with different code examples.
- Edits were made to the OP's code

Although in this case the edit looked benign, I wondered whether it is generally acceptable to make extensive edits to accepted answers, because readers may assume that the acceptance and upvotes were given to the answer as it is displayed.

UPDATE: This is the edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9491974
In the meantime it has been rejected; the only user who accepted it is someone with an 100% accept rate.

Comment: Any post is allowed to be edited, so the fact that it's accepted should make no difference. Examine the content not the accept vote.

Comment: " because readers may assume that the acceptance and upvotes were given to the answer as it is displayed" would be an argument for not allowing extensive edits to any answer at all - whether made by the OP or anyone else.

In reality such extensive edits have virtually no chance of making it through the suggested edits system and will almost always be rejected except if the original post author uses their right to unilaterally approve edits before this happens.

Comment: Since the original author of the edit 'did not care' after a year to post it as answer, I reposted the edit's [content](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36615788/2279200) because I think the content is valuable. I do not know if this was the right move or if I should maybe make it a community wiki.